# Is it possible to have more than one checkbox in TabWidget (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

If I have like three different tabs and I want to have 3 checkboxes in each of the tabs, is this possible. Please explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is, try to add a `Layout.xml` for each tab and each activity in wich you added three checkboxes.

Try to start with a TabWidget tutorial to start off with something ;)
-> http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: did edit my post. upvotes and answerAccepts are appreciated ;)